# it may sound like a trivial question but who i make my layout scrollable

Tags: android

scrollable meaning by the user touch he can can go up and down in the layout given

this is what i did and the emulator throw an exception null pointer somthing and i have problems figuring out from where it comes ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">


<LinearLayout

 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView 
 android:text="Country City Game(aka CCG) is an acdemic work of MTA students enjoy the game"
  android:textSize="24.5sp"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>
 </LinearLayout>




</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this one doesnt work but when i drop

```
   <ScrollView> </ScrollView>
```

it works can some one explain to me what's wrong ?

Comment: You've edited the question to include the suggested answers - this is now confusing. You should mention in the edit that you have done that, or anyone else viewing this question later may not understand what the problem & related solution is. StackOverflow isn't just for getting *your* questions answered, its for building a repository of Q&A to help developers.

Comment: it's the same question i just added more text and example in order to help others see the all picture annd i might be wrong in another place ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow>

  <TextView 
   android:text="Country City Game(aka CCG) is an acdemic work of MTA students enjoy the game"
   android:textSize="24.5sp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thank you but still it has a runtime error ... can you see the code above (i just added him) and tell me what's wrong ?...

Answer (score 0):

Surround the layout you want to have a scroll bar attached with a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put your entire layout that you want to be able to scroll inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: Sorry for double posting. I see now that ccheneson responded a bit faster.

Comment: please notice the changes up , i thought i am already tried what you were saying but i thought i am not in the right direction might it be something wrong in me getting the concept ? should i do <scrollView> to every View item?